# wpf checkbox doesn't display over citrix

Tags: wpf, citrix

So we have a WPF app deployed on a citrix server, it all works fine except that the checkbox won't show that it has been clicked (it's actually working just fine). So weird - just that one little thing, I have buttons which I have customized the pooh out of using visual states and those are all fine. A google search of "wpf checkbox citrix" turns up nothing useful. Anyone seen this or have an idea where to look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some incompability between the display driver, Citrix, and the CheckBox default style for the active Windows theme.  I would write a simple CheckBox template (I can include one if you need) and see if that works, and if it does, use that instead of the default theme style.

Comment: Yeah - grumble grumble... I will need to deal with that.

Comment: Well, like I said, let me know if you'd like a sample one.

Comment: Huh - I whipped up a quick template in Blend 4 and it solves the issue, the funny thing is that I have other check boxes on this form and they are OK... I haven't sorted it out yet - Obviously the immediate problem is solved but I don't have the deeper understanding of it at the moment.